# How to clear value of text field in jquery.businesshours when checkbox is de-checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to clear the value of the `startTime` and `endTime` values. The problem is, the `textboxes` all have the same name, so if I clear one they all get cleared. I'm not sure how to select just the particular instance since they all have the same name... that's how `jquery.businesshours` operates.

Below clears the text field, but it clears all of them.

```
container.find("[name='startTime[]']").val('');
```

Below is the javascript code

```js
/**
 jquery.businessHours v1.0.1
 https://github.com/gEndelf/jquery.businessHours

 requirements:
 - jQuery 1.7+

 recommended time-picker:
 - jquery-timepicker 1.2.7+ // https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker
 **/

(function($) {
    $.fn.businessHours = function(opts) {
        var defaults = {
            preInit: function() {
            },
            postInit: function() {
            },
            inputDisabled: false,
            checkedColorClass: "WorkingDayState",
            uncheckedColorClass: "RestDayState",
            colorBoxValContainerClass: "colorBoxContainer",
            weekdays: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
            operationTime: [
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {isActive: false},
                {isActive: false}
            ],
            defaultOperationTimeFrom: '',
            defaultOperationTimeTill: '',
            defaultActive: !0,
            //labelOn: "Working day",
            //labelOff: "Day off",
            //labelTimeFrom: "from:",
            //labelTimeTill: "till:",
            containerTmpl: '<div class="clean"/>',
            dayTmpl: '<div class="dayContainer">' +
            '<div data-original-title="" class="colorBox"><input type="checkbox" class="invisible operationState"/></div>' +
            '<div class="weekday"></div>' +
            '<div class="operationDayTimeContainer">' +
            '<div class="operationTime"><input type="text" name="startTime[]" class="mini-time operationTimeFrom" value=""/></div>' +
            '<div class="operationTime"><input type="text" name="endTime[]" class="mini-time operationTimeTill" value=""/></div>' +
            '</div></div>'
        };

        var container = $(this);

        function initTimeBox(timeBoxSelector, time, isInputDisabled) {
            timeBoxSelector.val(time);

            if(isInputDisabled) {
                timeBoxSelector.prop('readonly', true);
            }
        }

        var methods = {
            getValueOrDefault: function(val, defaultVal) {
                return (jQuery.type(val) === "undefined" || val == null) ? defaultVal : val;
            },
            init: function(opts) {
                this.options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
                container.html("");

                if(typeof this.options.preInit === "function") {
                    this.options.preInit();
                }

                this.initView(this.options);

                if(typeof this.options.postInit === "function") {
                    //$('.operationTimeFrom, .operationTimeTill').timepicker(options.timepickerOptions);
                    this.options.postInit();
                }

                return {
                    serialize: function() {
                        var data = [];

                        container.find(".operationState").each(function(num, item) {
                            var isWorkingDay = $(item).prop("checked");
                            var dayContainer = $(item).parents(".dayContainer");

                            data.push({
                                isActive: isWorkingDay,
                                timeFrom: isWorkingDay ? dayContainer.find("[name='startTime[]']").val() : null,
                                timeTill: isWorkingDay ? dayContainer.find("[name='endTime[]']").val() : null
                            });
                        });

                        return data;
                    }
                };
            },
            initView: function(options) {
                var stateClasses = [options.checkedColorClass, options.uncheckedColorClass];
                var subContainer = container.append($(options.containerTmpl));
                var $this = this;

                for(var i = 0; i < options.weekdays.length; i++) {
                    subContainer.append(options.dayTmpl);
                }

                $.each(options.weekdays, function(pos, weekday) {
                    // populate form
                    var day = options.operationTime[pos];
                    var operationDayNode = container.find(".dayContainer").eq(pos);
                    operationDayNode.find('.weekday').html(weekday);

                    var isWorkingDay = $this.getValueOrDefault(day.isActive, options.defaultActive);
                    operationDayNode.find('.operationState').prop('checked', isWorkingDay);

                    var timeFrom = $this.getValueOrDefault(day.timeFrom, options.defaultOperationTimeFrom);
                    initTimeBox(operationDayNode.find('[name="startTime[]"]'), timeFrom, options.inputDisabled);

                    var endTime = $this.getValueOrDefault(day.timeTill, options.defaultOperationTimeTill);
                    initTimeBox(operationDayNode.find('[name="endTime[]"]'), endTime, options.inputDisabled);
                });

                container.find(".operationState").change(function() {
                    var checkbox = $(this);
                    var boxClass = options.checkedColorClass;
                    var timeControlDisabled = false;


                    if(!checkbox.prop("checked")) {
                        // disabled
                        boxClass = options.uncheckedColorClass;
                        timeControlDisabled = true;
                    }

                    checkbox.parents(".colorBox").removeClass(stateClasses.join(' ')).addClass(boxClass);
                    checkbox.parents(".dayContainer").find(".operationTime").toggle(!timeControlDisabled);
                }).trigger("change");

                if(!options.inputDisabled) {
                    container.find(".colorBox").on("click", function() {
                        var checkbox = $(this).find(".operationState");
                        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop('checked')).trigger("change");
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        return methods.init(opts);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If you put this in a JSFiddle or CodePen it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: If the HTML for each `dayTmpl` is the same, you'll need to add some type of unique identifier or rely on their order on the DOM. If you added a `data-weekday` attribute to the day container, then you can change your selector to `container.find(\`.dayContainer[data-weekday="${weekdayIdx}"]\`)`

Comment: I will try and put together something.

Comment: Yes, the HTML for each dayTmpl is the same. I'm not sure how to add the data-weekday attribute so I can uniquely identify the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following code in the comments that is used to clear the input:

```
if(!options.inputDisabled) {
    container.find(".colorBox").on("click", function() {
        var checkbox = $(this).find(".operationState");
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop('checked')).trigger("change");
        container.find(.dayContainer[data-weekday="4"] [name='startTime[]']).val('');
        container.find(.dayContainer[data-weekday="4"] [name='endTime[]']).val('');
});
```

We can change the onClick handler to change the start and end times that have the same parent as the `.colorBox`.

```
if (!options.inputDisabled) {
    container.find(".colorBox").on("click", function(event) {
        var checkbox = $(this).find(".operationState");
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop('checked')).trigger("change");

        var $dayContainer = $(event.target).closest('.dayContainer');
        $dayContainer.find('[name="startTime[]"]').val('');
        $dayContainer.find('[name="endTime[]"]').val('');
    });
```

}

Comment: This seems to work with giving it a unique identifier, but it creates many more blocks. https://i.imgur.com/IkK2muf.png Edit: Removed the following from the original code, now it's outputting the correct amount of days: for(var i = 0; i < options.weekdays.length; i++) {
                    subContainer.append(options.dayTmpl);
                }

Comment: Hah, that looks terrible. Sorry.

Comment: Without debugging it I'm not sure where it broke Ian. Does that look over each weekday look like a good spot to add the unique ID? Right by: `initTimeBox(operationDayNode.find('[name="startTime[]"]'), timeFrom, options.inputDisabled);` I'll edit the answer ...

Comment: Right under the initView, they had a for loop. I replaced that one with yours and it works. Now, I can't figure out how to identify the unqiue identifier to clear the value. I can only hard code it. How would you know which identifier it came from? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Where is that element being added? Is it in the code above?

Comment: if(!options.inputDisabled) {
                    container.find(".colorBox").on("click", function() {
                        var checkbox = $(this).find(".operationState");
                        checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop('checked')).trigger("change");
                        container.find(`.dayContainer[data-weekday="4"] [name='startTime[]']`).val('');
                        container.find(`.dayContainer[data-weekday="4"] [name='endTime[]']`).val('');


                    });

Comment: Cool! I think that means your `.colorBox` element has the same parent as the start and end time. We can simplify this a ton.

Comment: I believe so. Also, operationDayTimeContainer is the div that holds operationTime input-group div which holds the text field. There are two operationTime input-group divs, one for startTime and one for endTime

Comment: Your fix works perfectly! Thank you so much Sean. Much appreciated.